# Passing Integer parameter from Vb6 to C++ dll

Tags: c++, vb6

```
Public Declare Function getTable Lib "LuxDll.dll" (ByVal table As Integer, _
     ByVal col As Integer) As String

BSTR _stdcall getTable(int table, int col)

Dim i
i=5
debug.print getTable(i, 1)
```

The above works

but if I did "Dim i as integer" it crashes

should the parameters in VB be something other than integer?

Thanks

EDIT: I should specify the C++ side crashes and its because the integer value gets passed as -65000ish

Comment: haha, I should have tried this before asking.. that worked :D thanks.. also thanks for the edit (I always butch the formatting lol).  Should I change the byval table as integer and col as integer to longs too?  it seems to work with them as integers but I dont understand why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In mixing VB6 with C/++, a C int equates to a Long in VB6: so `Dim i As Long` should work.  That is no longer true in .NET.  And though you had it right, it should be BYVAL (another common mistake)

Answer (score 1):

When I do something like this, I try to be very explicit with my types. Int changes from implementation to implementation, platform to platform.

Use `signed long`, or the equivalent type in VB `Int32` everywhere, instead of int or integer. That will save you lots of pain.

There's also something to be said for being explicit about your types for documentation purposes. I have had tons of problems trying to get a DLL from a vendor with bad documentation working. Something as simple as saying Int64, or unsigned short will go a long way to informing someone trying to interface with your DLL how it is to be dealt with.